# Taking screenshot of VMware Virtual OS using host OS java application (java Robot)

Tags: java, screen-scraping, screenshot, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have developed a java application which takes a screenshot using robot (presses "Print Screen"). Problem is, it won't work if i move to VMware's Virtual OS. Java application running is host OS continuously presses "Print Screen" and saves it. As long as i'm in host OS it works just fine but when VMware grabs input the screenshots stop to be updated, looks like host OS can't press anymore keys when input is grabbed by virtual OS.

Has anyone any clues regarding to make this work: host java application presses "Print Screen" and when i have moved to virtual OS then the java application can save the virtual OS screenshots.

Regards,
KMI

Comment: is it possible to share your program i have the similar requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about VMware, but I use VirtualBox.  VirtualBox will grab the input.  There is a Host key - the right Ctrl key - which will return the input to the host OS.

So it is likely that VMware has a similar Host key.  If so, you must modify your Robot to press the Host key.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, when i was on vmware application (not directly in virtual OS) the default short key(host key) Ctrl+Alt works. Fortunately Java robot can take screenshots from host OS when i'm operating in virtual OS, so it solves my problem. Thank you again!